# Setting Image.Flags for a Bitmap object in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, bitmap

I'm trying to find a way to set the Image.Flags property (System.Drawing namespace) for bitmap images that I'm outputting from a VB script using .NET Framework 4.5.1. [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.flags(v=vs.100).aspx) states that the Image.Flags property is a ReadOnly property, but is there any possible way, through the Metadata or anything else, to change the flags when converting an Image object to a Bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

You don't set the flags directly; the flags are just used to describe the bitmap.

Here is an example where we check if a bitmap has an alpha channel (transparency) then check a different bitmap without an alpha channel

Form's PictureBox1 has image with transparent background

[image]

```
Dim b As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image) ' this image has alpha
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Has Alpha: {0}", (b.Flags And ImageFlags.HasAlpha) > 0))
Dim c = New Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb) ' convert to no alpha
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Has Alpha: {0}", (c.Flags And ImageFlags.HasAlpha) > 0))
```

The messageboxes would output `Has Alpha: true`, `Has Alpha: false`

So I have effectively set the alpha flag, but only by actually changing the corresponding underlying property.

If you didn't know, as shown in the example, flags are a bitmask and when `And` with a value of `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat`, one can check if the flag is high (result is > 0).